# DataSet tables copying error

Tags: c#, mysql, dataset

I am getting the follwing error when trying to copy a table from a MySQL connection to a DataSet.

> Mouse drag operation failed. could not retrieve schema information for
>   table or view

I've seen the same problem on SO.. and the answers typically go in the order of reinstalling MySQL for Visual Studio and the MySQL connector, in the given order.

I've done the exact same thing, with the following versions:

1. mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.8
2. mysql-connector-net-8.0.11

But I'm still getting the same error. I don't get it why.

By the way, I used to create the project on a different computer, where the adapters where working normally.

Any clues?

Comment: Try the solution from the following link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238872/entity-framework-your-project-references-the-latest-version-of-entity-framework/53537476#53537476

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. After hours and hours of tinkering I found out that the current versions of MySql-for-visual-studio and MySqlConnector/Net have a bug, which can only be fixed by unninstalling those and installing `MySQL-for-visual-studio-1.2.6.msi` and `MySqlConnector-6.9.8.msi`, exactly in this order.

Comment: These are not available for Visual Studio 2017.